# A word problem that uses the contrapositive of the pigeonhole principle

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics

> A group of $15$ executives are to share $5$ assistants. Each
>   executive is assigned exactly $1$ assistant, and no assistant is assigned to more than $4$ executives. Show that at least $3$ assistants are assigned to 3 or more executives.

I tried this below:

Suppose $2$ assistants are assigned to $3$ or more executives. Then the other $3$ assistants are assigned to at most $1$ executive. That means $2$ assistants serve at most $6$ executives and $3$ assistants serve at most $3$ execs by the contrapositive of the generalized pigeonhole principle. Altogether, $9$ executives are served by $5$ assistants which contradicts our assumption of $15$ executives. Does it make sense?

Comment: Not exactly...you assume the two assistants are assigned to $3$ or more, not $3$ exactly.  As the max is $4$ execs (by assumption) those two could be assigned to $8$, then the other $3$ assistants cover $2$ execs each, for a total of $8+6=14$.

Comment: @lulu, I see. That's perfect. Than you.

Answer (score 1):

I think It way be easier to look at a proof by contradiction, as that uses the regular pigeonhole principle.

The statement can be rephrased as "*At most* 2 assistants are assigned $2$ or fewer executives." Its negation is thus "*More than* $2$ assistants are assigned $2$ or fewer executives." We can show that this statement cannot be true.

If more than $2$ assistants are assigned to $2$ or fewer executives, we can always choose exactly $3$ of these assistants. These $3$ are assigned at most $6$ individual executives. The remaining executives, of which there are at least $9$, must be distributed among the remaining $2$ assistants. It is clear that this cannot be done without assigning one of the assistants to more than $4$ executives.

We can therefore conclude that if the statement is not satisfied, it is not a valid configuration. If there exists any valid configuration (which we have not proven), it will necessarily satisfy the statement.